# How To Unit Test Multiple Instances Of Class In xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm fairly new to unit testing. I understand the concept, but I keep find myself bumping into walls with the execution. How, in xUnit, do I test multiple instances of a class? For instance, say I have a constructor with a signature:

```
public FileWatcher(string path = "", bool startWatching = true)
```

I want to run all of my unit tests for each public property and method that I'm testing against multiple instances of `FileWatcher`, each with the constructor passed different arguments. This way I can run all of my tests against an instance of `FileWatcher` where no arguments were passed in, and then one where arguments were. I don't know if what I'm trying to do reeks of code smell or if I don't know the correct nomenclature to turn up any results, but I can't find *anything* on this subject.

Comment: You always can write own test method for every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you should think about your approach. From the signature, I think your `FileWatcher` should/would/does behave differently when `path` is null, when file exists, when the file does not exist.

There is not much point in testing the same scenario over and over, because you're basically running the *same* test.

You should try to find different edge cases and ideally create one test for each.

That said, it is possible to create Theories in xUnit, these are tests with parameters. I would suggest [xUnit Theory: Working With InlineData, MemberData, ClassData](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/), this helped me.

Comment: I agree. I think I was getting ahead of myself. I'm going just run some test against the constructor(s) specifically. This was invaluable information though. Thank you!